# What is the reason behind facebook error with code 200 and subcode 1487194 when creating ads?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, social-media

The error description says:

`Either the object you are trying to access is not visible to you or the action you are trying to take is restricted to certain account types`

which can be found on facebook documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference?locale=en_US

But it does not specify why that might be the case. I'm currently trying to publish a facebook ad, and have an app in live mode with the following permissions already approved:

`ads_management, business_management,pages_manage_ads,pages_read_engagement`.

The request to create the ad works well with a test user but does not work with a real account.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have figured it out by myself.

I have got the same error while boosting a listing in the marketplace.

In my case, it´s because an ad payment method has to be added in the account, stating if selling for business or not.
These settings have to be configured in the Ads setting page:
https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/account_settings

Comment: I have had this issue using Ads Manager as well. I create a campaign and then get "Account Disabled" shortly after, and editing the ad shows the 1487194 error message. Do you know if it matters if the payment is added to the Ad Account or to the Business itself? I have had to request re-enabling my account several times now with Facebook only saying "There was some unusual activity on your ad account, so we're protecting it by stopping your ads. We'll start your ads again using your current balance once you verify your account with us."